# AWS Windows EC2 Startup scripts not running

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2019

Created a Windows Server 2019 EC2 Instance. Using PowerShell Scripts in CloudFormation UserData, I created a bat file (which pings another machine) and copied it over to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" and did a restart. However, the startup script is not executed unless I login into the machine. What could be issue? Is there a way to start the script without logging in.

Comment: What you describe is "works as designed", you need a different approach. Perhaps some kind of service. What's the idea behind the ping stuff?

Comment: the bat file contains steps to execute selenium jar. The Windows EC2 Instance will behave as selenium agent and should connect to Selenium Hub (another EC2 instance).